# Menu actions in QGIS 2.6 feature attributes

Tags: qgis

I would like to ask about new menu 'actions' in feature attributes which appears in new QGIS 2.6. This menu shows 'actions', defined for the layer but I am wondering if it is possible to add some other menus in features attributes window (for example group actions in different menu bars).
I didn't find anything in QGIS layer properties but maybe it's possible in QT designer?